Is there an easier way to generate Brillouin zone $\mathbf{k}$-points of FCC lattice?
I am new to working with 3D lattices and am wondering if there are any well-developed methods for generating all $\mathbf{k}$-points inside the first Brillouin zone (BZ) of an FCC lattice.
I use the following primitive lattice vectors:

$a_1 = \frac{a}{2} (\hat y+\hat z)$
$a_2 = \frac{a}{2} (\hat x+\hat z)$
$a_3 = \frac{a}{2} (\hat x+\hat y)$

where $a$ is the length of the conventional cubic unit cell of the FCC lattice. From these, I calculate the reciprocal lattice vectors $b_1$, $b_2$, and $b_3$ (which of course form a BCC lattice). The reciprocal lattice defined by $G=hb_1+kb_2+lb_3$ is shown in the figure below with $(h,k,l)$ points:

I do not how to further bisect these connecting lines to define the first BZ and accurately generate $\mathbf{k}$-points within it.
It feels like I am reinventing the wheel; there must be some well-developed method for generating $\mathbf{k}$-points for the FCC lattice. Is there a straightforward method for obtaining all $\mathbf{k}$-points within the first BZ of an FCC lattice with lattice constant $a$?

The first Brillouin zone consists of the points closer to the origin than to any of the neighboring points. In the reciprocal bcc lattice the neighbors that are involved are the "body points" of the $8$ cubic cells around the origin. Corner points never come into play, if you move away from the origin one of the $8$ points mentioned become your nearest grid point once you leave the first BZ. Since the cubic cell has side $4\pi/a$, those $8$ body points are:
$$ \frac{2\pi}{a} \, (\, \pm 1,\, \pm 1,\, \pm 1\,)
$$
Being closer to the origin than any of those points gives $8$ equations, obtained by selecting each of the $\pm$ sign choices in:
$$  \pm\, k_x \pm k_y \pm k_z\ < \frac{3\pi}{a}   \tag{1}
$$
If we take the three $+$ signs, for instance, the equation tells us how far we can move towards the body center at position $(\frac{2\pi}{a},\frac{2\pi}{a},\frac{2\pi}{a})$, obviously until we reach the plane $k_x + k_y + k_z\ =\frac{3\pi}{a}$, which is exactly halfway, and normal to the $111$-direction.
You could use this to generate $k$-points within the first BZ, by selecting the three $k$ components as random numbers in the range $[-\frac{2\pi}{a},\frac{2\pi}{a}]$, and then rejecting the selection and selecting again if one of the equations is violated. Or instead of rejecting the $k$ vector, you could mirror it in the plane that was crossed. (The latter would still give a uniform distribution and would make sure that the algorithm gives a selected $k$ in finite time! Although actually there is only 50$\%$ chance of a violation for each randomly chosen $k$, it could in theory take many attempts...)
